# Implementing Passport.JS

Tags: authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to create an authentication system using passport-local in MERN Stack. However, I have been stuck for days now. The registration process works perfectly but the login in process keeps on telling me incorrext username and password. Please assit!

Here are my core files: Server.js,user.model and user.js(holding register and login routes) and this is what I did:

```
//Server.js

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
app.use(cors(), express.json());

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my-secret-key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


const User = require('./models/user.model');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  (username, password, done) => {
    User.findOne({ userName: username }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
        if (result) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong password' });
        }
      });
    });
  }
));



passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


const usersRouter = require('./routes/user');

app.use('/user', usersRouter);


// Make connection
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

mongoose.connection.once('open', ()=>{
    console.log('Connected to the database Successful');
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`You are listening to port ${port}`);
});






//user.model

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        userName:{
            type:String,
            required: true
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            required: true
        }
    }
);

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

module.exports = User;


//user.js


const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');

// add user
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const userName = req.body.userName;
  const password = req.body.password;

  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json('Error hashing password.');
    }

    const newUser = new User({
      userName,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    newUser
      .save()
      .then(() => res.json('User Added Successfully'))
      .catch((err) => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });
});


// Login Route

router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Incorrect username or password.' });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      req.flash('success', 'Login successful!');
      return res.json('User authenticated successfully');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});








module.exports = router;
```